# Gas oven tripping GFCI outlet

Tags: gas, stove

After replacing igniter on Samsung has stove it keeps tripping GFCI outlet downstream from stove. The oven will reach temp then trip the GFCI. After resetting GFCI the oven runs fine.

Comment: If GFI started tripping after you replaced something, I would suspect the work was not perfect, a small nick in a wire might do it.

Comment: Where is this GFCI located? What do you mean "downstream from the stove"? Is this the receptacle supplying 120 V power to the stove? Is this oven heated by gas? The electric power is only for controls or ignitors?